# One specific html page in my website displays properly when previewed but displays incorrectly live

Tags: html, css

I designed a Mobile-first responsive site www.designsbykyram.com

When previewing http://www.designsbykyram/photography.html in the browser, it displays properly with the design I created for it for all pages displaying on screens larger than 950px with LargeDevice.css, but only when live on the web, it displays as if it was being shown on a tablet and reading the css file for tablet sizes.

The page is configured Exactly the same way as the others , yet displaying differently only when live, what am I doing wrong here?

Of course I made sure the page was uploaded to the same folder online as locally since I just dragged and dropped the entire directory over to the web

This is a helpful image visually showing what the problem is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typing error in there use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:950px)" href="css/largeDevice.css">
```

remove capital L

Your local machines filesystem probably ignores capitals and the server does not.

Comment: I upvoted, how can I accept your answer? sorry it's my first day on stackoverflow

Comment: @KyramKiwiSingletonofDBK There should be a grey check mark under the votes that turns green on hover click on that.

Comment: For new members there are built-in delays. Patience. :)